# How to filter(search) a list

Tags: search, custom-list, filter, tags

I'm not sure if this can be achieved with Filter or need to create a search function.

I have a list with about 500 items with potential to grow to several thousand. I want to give user ability to type in a word in text box and to only show items in the list that matches that.

Also I want to be able to define which rows are returned by having "tags" on each row so I can return more rows that match specific filter(search) criteria without actually containing it.

Sharepoint 2010

Comment: what version of SharePoint are you dealing with?  Also, Your question might be misunderstood by a lot of people, you might want to clarify what it is you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a list in a view based on a textbox using SharePoint Designer. The basic steps include:

1. Add an ASP.NET textbox control to your page
2. Add the XSLTListView webpart (if it's not already there)
3. Click the XSLTListView webpart and click Parameters.
4. Add a Control Parameter and find the textbox control ID from the drop-down. Name it something distinct (FilterParam) Click OK.
5. Click the XSLTListView webpart again and click Filter
6. Find the column you want to filter, select the operand, then find the parameter you just made from the name you gave it. (FilterParam). Click OK
7. Save the page, publish, and check it in if necessary.

[Customizing SharePoint List Views with SharePoint Designer 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300163.aspx) (same concept for 2010)

Comment: Also, not sure what you mean by your "tags" paragraph.

Comment: Thanks a lot that really help. Now I just need to figure how to make my List refresh after I type in the value in text box

Comment: Your answer was enough for me to figure out what to do with "Tags". Basically I will add extra column that will contain some values that will be used to filter the list instead of the title column

Comment: One more question: How would I clear that filter if someone wanted to see everything?

Comment: Two ways: 1. Have a seperate button that clear's the textbox. 2. Show/Provide a seperate view (usually AllItems.aspx is default) that has no filter; warn users that filtered view is only for filtering.

Comment: Mike, I took your second advice and just created different view for showing the whole thing and one just for filter/search. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your list as a lookup list then you can try using my free tool [SharePoint 2010 Autocomplete Lookup Field](http://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/)
However, if you want to create a webpart with textbox, you can use Jquery along with REST to search the list as shown in this example:
[Autocomplete TextBox using JQuery and REST](http://tomvangaever.be/blogv2/2011/07/sharepoint-2010-autocomplete-with-list-items/)